# Geoserver SLD scale based view for multiple geometry styles

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

I have a FeatureStyle that draws line and adda an arraow to end point of the line. And I want to see this line and arrow by scale. So I specified a **MaxScaleDenominator** property. Now line is not appearing at scale but arrow is appearing. How can I solve this issue? Can I specify multiple MaxScaleDenominator?

```
   <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
            <Name>Lines</Name>
            <ogc:Filter>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>line_type</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>middle</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:Filter>
            <MaxScaleDenominator>6000</MaxScaleDenominator>
            <LineSymbolizer>
                <Stroke>
                    <CssParameter name="stroke">#aa0000</CssParameter>
                    <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
            </LineSymbolizer>                    
            <PointSymbolizer>
                <Geometry>
                    <ogc:Function name="endPoint">
                        <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                    </ogc:Function>
                </Geometry>
                <Graphic>
                    <Mark>
                        <WellKnownName>shape://oarrow</WellKnownName>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#fff433</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#fff433</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </Mark>
                    <Size>15</Size>
                    <Rotation>
                        <ogc:Function name="endAngle">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </ogc:Function>
                    </Rotation>
                </Graphic>
            </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
```

Comment: you can have multiple MaxScaleDenominator if you have multiple rules.. So I would define two rules, one for the LineSymbolizer and one for the PointSymbolizer. Not sure though what's the problem with your code..